# How to connect PostgreSQL database to Oracle

Tags: oracle, postgresql, database-migration, dblink, postgres-fdw

I have migrated an oracle database to AWS Aurora PostgreSQL. My application is connecting to another upstream application on Oracle database on AWS RDS.

I'm generating inventory reports from the upstream application. earlier it was both Oracle databases, so they were using dblink to connect the upstream/downstream databases.

dblink and postgresql_fdw installed and both are connecting to the different postgres databases not to oracle db.

My question is how to I connect to Oracle db from postgres.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [Configuring Oracle Database Gateway for ODBC](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/gateways.111/b31042/configodbc.htm). When you install the Postgres ODBC drivers on your Oracle DB server, then connection from Oracle to Postgres (the opposite direction than you asked) should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. You limited yourself by choosing a hosted database.

If you had control over the operating system, you could install oracle_fdw, and it would be simple.

Comment: I've the control on the OS. I've a postgres db is running on my local machine. is it possible to connect to oracle ?

Comment: Oh, yes, absolutely. The software and instructions are [here](https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw).

Comment: Cool :) Thanks Laurenz